# What would be an alternative for http.request()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've wrote a server base on nodejs and i need to write a tester for him.
It's forbidden to use http library.

What could be that alternative for `http.request()` to load a request   ?

I'm using it now like this :

```
var http = require("http");

function options()  {
    return {
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: null,
        path: '',
        method: '',
        headers: {}
    }
}
var req = http.request(opt, function(res) {
        var body = '';

        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
    });
```

Comment: maybe prohibited ?

Comment: Probably the `request()` library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: maybe forbidden ?

Comment: can you use other modules like `request` or `got` ?

Comment: Yes, It's seem like request module will work

Comment: Forbidden? Why? So instead you now have to write it from scratch on top of module `net` or load some 3rd party lib. What's the point? Especially since this is code for the _tests_.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use **fetch** which is supported by a lot of browsers today.
If needed you could additionally use the polyfill made by *github* for old browsers.

In case the use of **fetch** is also forbidden (for some weird reason) you can go old school and write your own request handler with **XMLHttpRequest**.

Comment: fetch is not supported on node, it's only a browser feature util

Comment: It doesn't say he's using Node to test his Node server.
Just that the server need to be tested from http request.
So I assumed the client code would run in a browser (or WebDriver).
Plus, there is also a fetch library for Node.

Comment: well I get that impression based on OP tags

Answer (score 0):

try 'node-rest-client' module this is full optional for handling requests the doc is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client)